# Slow performance with javascript/html canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, canvas

So, I've created myself a little demo with javascript/html canvas in the context of a gameloop. You can move a small square by pressing the w,a,s,d keys. However, when held down for more than 3 or 4 seconds, the canvas becomes stuttery and the square almost stops moving.

Here's the javascript;

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// -- MAIN GAME LOOP
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
function gameLoop(){
    update();
    render();
    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

function update(){
    processInput();
};
function render(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('viewport');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    if(upDown){
        rect.top -= rect.speed;
    }else if(downDown){
        rect.top += rect.speed;
    }else if(leftDown){
        rect.left -= rect.speed;
    }else if(rightDown) {
        rect.left += rect.speed;
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(rect.left, rect.top, 50, 50, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
};

var rect = {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    speed: 5
};

// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// -- OTHER FUNCTIONS
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
var rightDown = false;
var leftDown = false;
var upDown = false;
var downDown = false;

function processInput(){
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        console.log(e.keyCode);
        if(e.keyCode == 87){upDown = true;}
        if(e.keyCode == 83){downDown = true;}
        if(e.keyCode == 68){rightDown = true;}
        if(e.keyCode == 65){leftDown = true;}
    }).keyup(function(){
        upDown = false;
        downDown = false;
        rightDown = false;
        leftDown = false;
    })
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
});
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Here's my codepen;

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKGJOr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're calling `processInput` (via `update`) within your gameloop.  This function is attaching new `keydown` and `keyup` event handlers *every time it is called*.  It's only necessary to call it once.  Remove the call from `update`, and (for example) call it within the `ready` function instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    processInput();
    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
});
```

By registering more and more event handlers, you're causing a lot more code to run than is necessary, hence the stuttering.

[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyqVzG).

Comment: That fixed it, you legend! Thank you!